# Is the solution to this SDE always positive?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and consider the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t, \, \, \, X_0 = 1 \, \text {a.s.}$$

Assume $\sigma$ is regular enough that the above SDE admits a globally defined solution.

Suppose $|\sigma(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

**Question:** Is it true that almost surely, $X_t > 0$ for all $t$?

It seems like the Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem may help, but I’m not sure how to turn it into a proof.

Comment: Isn't the CIR model a counterexample?  Recall that the CIR solution is a.s. positive only if the drift is sufficiently large; see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox–Ingersoll–Ross_model

Comment: Hm but that has a $-r_t \, dt$ drift term. Does removing that change anything?

Comment: To be sure, the drift coefficient is of the form $a (b-r_t)$, the noise coefficient is $\sigma \sqrt{r_t}$ and the positivity condition (just an instance of Feller's boundary classification) is $2 a b \ge \sigma^2$.  So if $a=0$, this condition cannot be met.

Comment: Ah, this is a hole in my knowledge… what is a good reference to read about Feller’s boundary classification work?

Comment: This looks like an "accessible" reference (no pun intended) that considers CIR as a special case (see Example 2.4) https://gradmath.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Jilani-trabelsi-final-2016.pdf See also references therein.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Name of @NawafBou-Rabee's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427153/is-the-solution-to-this-sde-always-positive#comment1098417_427153):  [ben Naouara and Trabelsi - A short review on boundary behavior of linear diffusion processes](https://gradmath.org/2020/10/05/a-short-review-on-boundary-behavior-of-linear-diffusion-processes/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement Nawaf's answer ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427153/is-the-solution-to-this-sde-always-positive#comment1098413_427153) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427153/is-the-solution-to-this-sde-always-positive#comment1098415_427153)), I thought I'd present a short argument how with some additional regularity assumptions, the answer is in fact yes.

Suppose that $\sigma\in{C^{2}(\mathbb{R})}$ with $\sigma(0)=0$. Then $\sigma$ is locally Lipschitz, which is sufficient to give us existence and pathwise uniqueness for the solution of the SDE:
$$
dX_{t}=\sigma(X_{t})dB_{t}, \hspace{10pt}X_{0}=x_{0}
$$
for any choice of $x_{0}\in{\mathbb{R}}$ (see theorem 6.9 of [Miller - Stochastic calculus](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk//%7Ejpm205/teaching/lent2016/lecture_notes.pdf)). Since $X_t=0$ is a perfectly valid solution to the above SDE when $X_0=0$, it is actually *THE* solution. By the strong Markov property, if $X_t$ ever hits $0$, it is stuck there. Thus, to show that $X_{t}>0$ for all $t\geq{0}$ when $X_{0}=1$, it suffices to show that $X_{t}$ cannot hit $0$ in finite time.

Consider the process $U_t=\log(\sigma(X_t))$. Notice that $X_t$ hits a zero of $\sigma$ in finite time iff $U_t$ diverges to $-\infty$ in finite time. By Itô's formula,
$$
dU_t = \sigma'(X_t)dB_t + \frac{1}{2}\big(\sigma''(X_t)\sigma(X_t) - (\sigma'(X_t))^2\big)dt.
$$
This is a diffusion with bounded coefficients when $X_t$ lies in a neighborhood of $0$ (as per our regularity assumptions on $\sigma$). Thus, while $X_t$ lies in a neighborhood of $0$, $U_t$ cannot run away to $-\infty$ in finite time and so $X_{t}$ cannot hit $0$ in finite time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very cool trick to consider $\log \sigma(X_t)$.